# Perl Encryption to PHP Encryption conversion

Tags: php, algorithm, perl, encryption, cryptography

Im in the middle of converting a very uncommented / cryptic perl "webpage" to PHP, and I am stuck in the middle of trying to decrypt strings..

Here is a sample of the encrypted string

U2FsdGVkX1+EV7P6FpjSronQjGKl5nRd9CCBe2Z7a23t+MvdM1jg5VDgK73qIHJr

Here are the perl functions used to encrypt it

```
use Crypt::OpenSSL::AES;
use Crypt::CBC;
use MIME::Base64;


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub InitAES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 my ($k) = @_;

return (Crypt::CBC->new(
-key    => $k,
-cipher => "Crypt::OpenSSL::AES"
));
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 sub EnCryptAES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   {
 my ($d, $k) = @_;
if (!defined($d)) { return(0); }
if (!defined($k)) { return(0); }

 $cipher = &InitAES($k);

return (encode_base64($cipher->encrypt($d)));
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub DeCryptAES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 my ($e, $k) = @_;
 if (!defined($e)) { return(0); }
 if (!defined($k)) { return(0); }

 $cipher = &InitAES($k);
 return ($cipher->decrypt(decode_base64($e)));
}
```

If anyone can help me write a php function to decrypt this, it would greatly be appreciated, I have tried a few different functions I have found by searching and none seem to be working. I do have the password for the task as well.

Comment: Evidently it's AES encrypted using whatever key `$k` is, and base64-encoded for plain-text transmission.

Comment: I understand that.. But what PHP functions can I use to decrypt it? mcrypt doesnt seem to work

Comment: I think [`openssl_decrypt`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) can, if you pass the right `$method` and `$password`, but I'm not 100% sure. The comments on this page might be worth a read: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

Answer (score 0):

The perl code looks self-explanatory to me.

Check out PHP's `openssl_decrypt` documented at http://thefsb.tumblr.com/post/110749271235/using-opensslendecrypt-in-php-instead-of